# How to tie the Lifecycle for a Spring Bean to the webapps' lifecycle?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jetty

I want to create a bean that has `start()` and `stop()` methods. 
When the webapp's context is active, `start()` is called during Spring's runtime bootup. When the webapp is undeployed or stopped, the `stop()` method is invoked.

Is this correct: I annotate my `start()` method with `@PostConstruct` and the `stop()` method with `@PreDestroy` ?

Normally in the servlet world, I write a ServletContextListener.
Would I be able to access the ApplicationContext from the ServletContextListener ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either annotate your `start()` and `stop()` methods as you describe, or you can tell Spring to invoke them explicitly, e.g.

```
<bean class="MyClass" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop"/>
```

As for the `ServletContextListener`, it would not have easy access to the Spring context. It's best to use Spring's own lifecycle to do your bean initialization.

Answer (score 10):

Implement the [Lifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) or [SmartLifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) interfaces in your bean, as described in

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor

```
public interface Lifecycle {
  void start();
  void stop();
  boolean isRunning();
}
```

Your [ApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) will then cascade its start and stop events to all Lifecycle implementations.  See also the JavaDocs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html